# Attack on Double Encryption Scheme

Tags: attack, multiple-encryption

In this protocol:

1. A → B : { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B)
2. B → A : { <[B, {K}pk(A)]> }pk(A)

I'd like to determine why this is insecure.  How can the attacker learn the key K if A and B are both honest agents?

This is what I have started with:

1. A → B : { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B)

An attacker M can intercept this, however M cannot decrypt this.  M sends it to B so B thinks the message is coming from M:

2. M → B : { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B)

Then I run into the problem that A's identity is still in the message.  When B decrypts, he will realize that D and A do not match, and end the session.

Any help, hints, or advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why does B reply?

Comment: I think I've found the attack... Hint: What else can M do besides trying to forward / decrypt the message?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  I'm new to cryptography and am trying to learn on my own.  I came across this problem and it didn't come with a solution, but I'm having trouble coming up with my own!  Perhaps...What if M knows that A's identity will be the first part of the message?  M then knows what the first part should look like and can break the decrypted message that way?

Comment: Is the PKE scheme assumed to be CCA-secure? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, I'd think so. The attack I found doesn't need it to be non-CCA secure.

Comment: The attack doesn't work by breaking anything anyhow. M just does the right message interaction at the right time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have come up with a solution that makes the double encryption scheme problematic.

As in the protocol, A sends the packet to B:

A → B : { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B)

Now, let m1 be the entire packet and m2 be the encrypted key K:

m1 = <[A, {K}pk(B)]>

m2 = K

Some attacker M intercepts A's message.  M forms her own packet to send to B:

M → B : { <[M, {m1}pk(B)]> }pk(B)

Which is equivalent to:

M → B : { <[M, { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B)]> }pk(B)

B receives M's message.  He decrypts the first layer, see's M's identity, and decrypts the second layer to reveal what he believes the key K to be.  Then, following the protocol, B responds, encrypting with the public key of M since M's identity was in the message:

B → M : { <[B, {m1}pk(M)]> }pk(M)

Which is equivalent to:

B → M : { <[B, { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(M)]> }pk(M)

Now M has decrypted the first layer.  M again sends a message to B:

M → B : { <[M, {m2}pk(B)]> }pk(B)

Which is equivalent to:

M → B : { <[M, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B)

B responds similarly as before:

B → M : { <[B, {m2}pk(M)]> }pk(M)

Which is equivalent to:

B → M : { <[B, {K}pk(M)]> }pk(M)

And now M has the key K.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think what I do is provide a little more than a hint so don't read further if that is an issue.

> This problem is very much like the NSL protocol in that it allows an intermediary due to neither party declaring their own identity:

That is:

> `A -> E : { <[A, {K}pk(E)]> }pk(E) }`  `E -> B : { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B) }`  `B -> E : { <[B, {K}pk(A)]> }pk(A) }`  `E -> A the above`

Resulting in:

> Now B believes it has a shared channel with A but E is involved.  You can even simplify and omit A entirely since its existence was never proven to party B:

Alternatively:

> `E -> B : { <[A, {K}pk(B)]> }pk(B) }` `B -> anyone : { <[B, {K}pk(A)]>}pk(A) }`

and

> Now 'B' presumably believes key $K$ is shared with party $A$ when in fact party $E$ holds a copy.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just write up a nice answer on how I think the protocol is broken.
Read one hint by the other and think about each hint some time before proceeding to the next one. Their usefulness increases.

Hint 1:

> An attacker may not only observe packets but only drop or replace them.

Hint 2:

> The attack involves no decryption from the attacking party.

Hint 3:

> The attack assumes a man-in-the-middle scenario.

Hint 4:

> The attack would be prevented by *key confirmation*.

Hint 5:

> The attacker learns the secret key by supplying it.

Attack:

> A initiates a standard protocol run with B. M is a man-in-the-middle and drop A's initial packet. M formulates the packet $M\rightarrow B: \{ <[A, \{K_M\}pk(B)]> \}pk(B)$ with a $K_M$ of his choice. B continues the protocol as normal and sends the standard message to A except that $K$ is replaced by $K_M$ as he thinks, that's what A sent. Now M knows the shared key between both parties ($K_M$). This attack only works against the protocol given at hand. If A check wether $K=K_M$ he can find out that there was an attack and can alert B but if A just uses the key received in the second message, the attack works.